# NoSuchElementException Errors

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

Every time I go to compile my program, I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Pokedex.addPokemon(Pokedex.java:58)
    at PokemonProgram.Menu(PokemonProgram.java:93)
    at PokemonProgram.main(PokemonProgram.java:32)
```

The class PokemonProgram contains my main method and this seems to be the portion of code causing this issue

(PokemonProgram class)

```
case 3:                                   
    species = "";
    pokedex.addPokemon(species)
    Menu(scnr);
    break;
```

(Pokedex class)

```
public boolean addPokemon(String species) {                         

    boolean success = true;                                          //BOOLEAN FOR SUCCESSFULLY ADDING POKEMON
    dontWannaBeTheVeryBest++;

    if (dontWannaBeTheVeryBest > (Pokemons.length - 1)) {                //TEST FOR EXCEEDING POKEMONS SIZE
        success = false;
        System.out.println("Error: Pokedex is full!");
        dontWannaBeTheVeryBest--;
        System.out.println("");
    }

    if (success) {                                                             //CONTINUES ADDING OBJECT TO ARRAY IF MAX AND DUPLICATE CONDITIONS ARE FALSE
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the species to add: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);                            //Calls Pakuri constructor depended upon string
        while (true) {
            if (!scanner.hasNext()) {                                 //SOLUTION TO COMPILER ERROR
                scanner.next();
            } else {
                species = scanner.next();
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Please enter a valid size.");               //BOOLEAN FOR INVALID INPUT
            System.out.print("Enter max capacity of the Pokedex: ");
        }
        Pokemon store = new Pokemon(species);
        Pokemon[dontWannaBeTheVeryBest] = store;                             //STORES OBJECTS TO ARRAY
        size++;
        System.out.println("Pokemon species " + species + " successfully added!");
        System.out.println("");
    }
        return success;
    //RETURNS WHETHER OR NOT ADDING POKEMON WAS SUCCESSFUL
}
```

I've tried messing with .next() and .nextLine() but neither of these seem to solve my issue, what's wrong with my scanner?

Comment: `if (!scanner.hasNext()) { scanner.next();...` is specifically asking the scanner to give the next token when it _doesn't_ have it.That's probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if taking multiple inputs use while(scanner.hasNext()){species = scanner.nextLine()}. if only looking for one input (no matter what it is) just use species = scanner.nextLine(). if you only want the first word of the input line use scanner.next() instead

Comment: since you're trying to get an integer it looks, you can use scanner.nextInt() which gets the next integer in the input stream

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem code:

```
        if (!scanner.hasNext()) {    //SOLUTION TO COMPILER ERROR
            scanner.next();
        } else {
            species = scanner.next();
            break;
        }
```

The "then" part of the "if" statement is guaranteed to throw a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.  You call `scanner.hasNext()`, and when it returns `false` you call `next()` anyway.

I don't know what you refer to in `//SOLUTION TO COMPILER ERROR`, but this is NOT the correct solution.

> I've tried messing with .next() and .nextLine()  ...

Generally speaking, "messing around" is not a good way to design / implement good code.  What you need to do is carefully think through what the code is trying to do.  What questions are to be asked in what order, and what precisely your code should do in the cases of:

- an acceptable input value
- an unacceptable input value
- no value at all; i.e. EOF

In the case of unacceptable input (e.g. a non-integer when an integer is expected) you need to move past the input.  You also need to deal with the case of multiple "words" entered when you only expect one.

Comment: Can you point me in the correct direction? Unfortunately this issue only appears when submitting this project, not when running it in my own IDE so my trouble shooting is limited. What should I do in place of that code?

Comment: No I can't tell you what code to write.  I'm afraid that part of your code makes no sense to me.  I suggest you follow my advice ... starting with the "Generally speaking" sentence.